# Find the unique value of c which makes px a PMF

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let X have pmf
px(k) = P(X=k) = c * p^k / k, k=2,3,...

a. find the unique valye of c which makes px a PMF.

b. find E(X) and Var(X)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $x\in(0,1)$ let $\displaystyle f(x)=\sum_{k=2}^\infty\frac{x^k}k$. Then $f$ is differentiable and we may use term by term integration to get :
$$f'(x)=\sum_{k=2}^\infty x^{k-1}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty x^k=\frac{1}{1-x}-1$$
Therefore, by integrating we get $f(x)=-\ln(1-x)-x$. Therefore, we have :
$$\sum_{k=2}^\infty p_X(k)=cf(p)=c(-\ln(1-p)-p)$$
Hence $p_X$ is a PMF $\iff c=-\frac{1}{\ln(1-p)+p}$
The calculation for $\mathbb E[X]$ is direct and $\mathbb V[X]$ can be obtained analogously by letting $\displaystyle g(x)=\sum_{k=2}^\infty kx^k$ and then using Koenig's formula